# OMNeT++ issue with linking INET

Tags: omnet++, inet

During the build of my new `OMNeT++` project I have encountered following error:

`out/clang-debug//myUdp.o:(.rdata[_ZTI5myUdp]+0x10): undefined reference to 'typeinfo for inet::ApplicationBase'`

I have already configured `INET` reference (Project "myUdp" -> Properties -> Project reference -> inet checkbox selected)

**This is INET Makemake configuration:** [Target tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjqQu.png) and [Compile tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHCkx.png)

**This is Makemake configuration of my project (myUdp):** [Compile tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLEGL.png) and [Link tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZGpy.png)

**And the C++ code:**

MyUdp.cc

```
#include <inet/applications/udpapp/UDPBasicApp.h>
class myUdp: public inet::UDPBasicApp {
};
Define_Module(myUdp);
```

MyUdp.ned

```
import inet.applications.udpapp.UDPBasicApp;
simple myUdp extends UDPBasicApp {
    @class(myUdp);
}
```

Can somebody help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because UDPBasicApp's methods are defined as `virtual`.

Compare the GCC infos on "vague linking" from http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html, for example this part:

> `type_info` objects
>
> C++ requires information about types to be written out in order to
>   implement `dynamic_cast`, `typeid` and exception handling. For
>   polymorphic classes (classes with `virtual` functions), the `type_info`
>   object is written out along with the vtable so that `dynamic_cast` can
>   determine the dynamic type of a class object at run time. For all
>   other types, we write out the `type_info` object when it is used: when
>   applying `typeid` to an expression, throwing an object, or referring
>   to a type in a catch clause or exception specification.

You would need to provide either a definition for the virtual functions in the base class (UDPBasicApp) or declare them pure, because the compiler (GCC or Clang in your case) is trying to determine the right method for the translation unit (where the vtable and typeinfo objects are then created) and it cannot determine it correctly apparently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I've just realized that I mentioned different error in the original post. The error I am actually trying to solve reads `"undefined reference to typeinfo for inet::ApplicationBase"`. So my question is, should I declare all functions from ApplicationBase class in my own class?

Comment: Why not `extends ApplicationBase`?
The infos from my response still stand, take a look at the implementation of `UDPBasicApp`, it extends the `ApplicationBase` class and implements the pure virtual functions.